# Tomcat FORM-based authentication loads ajax content without page wrapper after session timeout

Tags: java, ajax, tomcat

Java application is loading raw ajax data after the session has timeout and the user logs back in.

Scenario:

1. User logs in successfully
2. Application loads and sits idle for the session timeout period
3. User selects an option that is an ajax call to refresh page content
4. Since the timeout period has passed, the user is redirected to the FORM-based login page defined in the WEB.XML file
5. User again logs in successfully
6. **Problem starts here:** Since the last URL request was for an ajax call, the page loads with the raw content without the full HTML page wrapper

**Question:** Since Tomcat is handling the Login and session creation process -

How can I handle this situation by either sending back a complete HTML page with the request or just send the user to the application landing page?

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping for a more elegant solution, but here's what I did to solve my issue.

At the top of my servlet controller I added the following code. If the sessions variable "FirstTimeIn" is null I know the user just logged in. I then check to see if the userPath is "/ajaxCall". I use this to identify all my ajax requests.  If the userPath is "/ajaxCall", I then redirect the user to the landing page of my web application.

```
if (session.getAttribute("FirstTimeIn") == null) {
        session.setAttribute("FirstTimeIn", "No");
        if (userPath.equals("/ajaxCall")) {
            response.sendRedirect("sc?action=dashboard");
        }
 }
```